# StringBuffer not giving ClassCastException when trying to add in a treeset without Comparator

Tags: java, treeset, stringbuffer

I was expecting the ClassCastException when trying to run the following piece of code:

```
 //  TreeSet<StringBuffer> t = new TreeSet<StringBuffer>((a, b) -> - 
  // a.toString().compareTo(b.toString()));
     TreeSet<StringBuffer> t = new TreeSet<StringBuffer>();
        Function<String, StringBuffer> f = s -> new StringBuffer(s);
        t.add(f.apply("A"));
        t.add(f.apply("M"));
        t.add(f.apply("B"));
        t.add(f.apply("Z"));
        t.add(f.apply("G"));
        System.out.println(t);
```

I have commented the Comparator code and was trying to use without the Comparator. But I am still getting the correct output. How is this possible because StringBuffer doesn't implement Comparable interface. I am using Java 11. Was there any changes made in the later version related to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are converting `StringBuffer` to `String` in comparator, and [String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) class implements `Comparable` interface, And also as a note since from jdk-11 [StringBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuffer.html)  and [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) also implements `Comparable`

```
(a, b) -> -a.toString().compareTo(b.toString())
```

But if you are on lower version below jdk-11 you will get the compile time error

> The method compareTo(StringBuffer) is undefined for the type StringBuffer

Comment: Sorry. I just edited the post. The comparator code is commented but still getting the correct output.

Comment: I was on 11 version. Thanks that was helpful.

Comment: check with lower version @RahulSharma and updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

It is possible because `StringBuffer` [*does*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) implement the `Comparable` interface.

Comment: Thanks. That was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

API Note:
StringBuffer implements Comparable but does not override equals. Thus, the natural ordering of StringBuffer is inconsistent with equals. Care should be exercised if StringBuffer objects are used as keys in a SortedMap or elements in a SortedSet. See Comparable, SortedMap, or SortedSet for more information.
Since:
1.0
See Also:
StringBuilder, String, Serialized Form
[https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuffer.html#:~:text=StringBuffer%20implements%20Comparable%20but%20does,or%20elements%20in%20a%20SortedSet%20](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuffer.html#:%7E:text=StringBuffer%20implements%20Comparable%20but%20does,or%20elements%20in%20a%20SortedSet%20).